# Google Cloud Project with No Owner

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, cloud, owner, google-iam

We have a Google Cloud project on my team and the owner has since left the organization.

We still have access to the project because someone on my team in an editor but editors cannot give others access. She is leaving the team and we are trying to give someone else access.

If there is no owner listed and the editor can't give access does that mean there is no way to give anyone else access or assign a new owner?[I have included a screenshot of the permissions page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3dX4.png)

Comment: 1) Check if any of the already created service accounts have the role Owner. 2) The simplest solution is to backup/move the resources to a project that you control/own. 3) Otherwise, you will need to go thru Google Cloud Support. The process will be easier if you own/control the billing account and the credit/debit card. 4) I am curious - how was the Owner Identity removed from the project?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to change the ownership :

Firstly check the created services have role owner or not then you need to back up the resources to a project that you can control or alternatively you will go through the GCP support  with the debit card or credit card credentials.

1. Click the "hamburger" menu button.
2. Select "IAM" under "Access" Click IAM.
3. At the top, click "ADD" Click ADD.
4. Name the new Owner and select "Owner" under "Project" Select Owner
   under Project.
5. Instruct your new Owner to Accept the Invitation.

Finally On a new Owner's account, go to Billing in the "hamburger" menu and either link     the  project to an existing billing account or set up a new Billing account to link the project On the new Owner's account, go back to the IAM section and delete your account from the list by clicking the pencil on the right and then the trash can icon. [Pencil Trash can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbHGQ.png)

I hope this is helpful